# How to turn off Kendo Menu on hover feature

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an image. Users hover over the image and the Kendo menu appears. I want to turn off the hover feature. I want users to click on the image to open the menu.

I am using MVC and the code starts something like this:

`@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
          .Name("MyMenu")
          .HoverDelay(500)
          .Items(parentMenu => parentMenu.Add().ImageUrl("www.someplace.com/someimage.jpg")
              .Items(items =>
                     {`

The main reason for doing this is that I recently upgraded to latest kendo and now the hoverdelay is completely messed up. Sometimes the menu closes even when the user is on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with [this](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [OpenOnClick](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/MenuBuilder#methods-OpenOnClick%28System.Boolean%29) setting:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Menu()
      .Name("menu")
      .OpenOnClick(true)
)
```

Comment: Brilliant. One thing though. The menu doesn't close on hover-out anymore.

Comment: Try setting CloseOnClick to false: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/MenuBuilder#methods-CloseOnClick(System.Boolean)

Comment: That didn't work. The menu opens when I click on the menu image but it doesnt close when I hover off the menu. Menu closes only if I click somewhere else on the page.

Comment: Yeah. This setting does a different thing. OpenOnClick makes the menu behave like the default Windows system menu. The latter doesn't close when the mouse leaves the item.